# check if element exists in priorityQueue of tuples

Tags: python, queue, priority-queue

Say I have this code:

```
q = PriorityQueue()
a = ((1,1), 10, 0)
b = ((2,2), 99, 200)
q.push(a, 1)
q.push(b, 2)
```

I'd like to check if the element (1,1) exists in any of the tuples in the queue. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: for PriorityQueue, it doesn't have a method "push", I think in your codes, you mean "put", am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `PriorityQueue` object stores its items in a list accessible via the [`queue` attribute](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/queue.py#L221). You can do:

```
>>> q = PriorityQueue()
>>> a = ((1, 1), 10, 0)
>>> q.put(a)
>>> any((1, 1) in item for item in q.queue)
True
```